# Как правильно произносить по-русски "Adobe"?

Tags: иностранные-слова

По-английски, если я ничего не путаю, читается "эдоуб". Но есть ли какая-то норма произношения названия этой фирмы по-русски? Адоб? Адоба? Эдоб?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это слово еще не имеет словарной фиксации в этом значении(в русском языке). Поэтому строго литературной нормы произношения еще не существует.НО.В английской транскрипции это слово произносится как эдоуб или эдоуби. **http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adobe**  Но вот что говорится в Википедии:*http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD* Но Адобе -произносится по-испански. Но, если учитовать, что фирма американская, и вся терминология на английском, то лучше произносить: **эдоуб**  - так как, на мой взгляд, оно больше соответствует нормам произношения русского языка.См.напр.здесь**.http://diductio.ru/course/1031/**

Comment: Адоб -- это скорее по-французски, испанское слово читается "адобе".

Comment: Вы правы - по -испански - адобе.